# Is it possible to set Sony A7S focus distance from a software remote?

Tags: camera, sony

I want to be able to manually set the focus distance on the camera by using a software remote of some kind. I will know a distance to an object I want to focus on but cannot use auto focus because objects will be passing in front of the camera.

Here are two possible remotes I have looked at.

1) Sony Remote Camera Control
http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/swu-download.pl?mdl=ILCE7&upd_id=9294&os_group_id=6

2) Camera Remote API
https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

Neither provide a way to set the focus distance that I can see. Is this even possible or just not documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible using the Camera Remote API.